# What does three semicolons (;) in Java mean?

Tags: java, for-loop

I was solving a few objective question in Java where I came across a statement like

```
for(i=0; i&lt ;l;i++)
```

Is it some kind of printing error or extra characters or does it have some meaning I don't 
understand exactly? Can anyone give a clear picture on this?

Comment: _statement like_ is never trustworthy. That `&lt ;` seems like a HTML entity.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `for(i=0; i<l;i++)`??

Comment: what's lt? can you say it's value or how it was declared?

Comment: ya i thought the same i<l but in between semi colon confused me. so wanted to be sure of what it is?

Comment: I guess the webpage where you saw this, didn't convert &lt ; into '<' because of the space in between t and semicolon

Answer (score 4):

That code has been passed through some sort of HTML filter, which replaces `<` with `&lt;`, because `<` is the start-tag character in HTML.

The *original* line would have been the correct syntax, something like:

```
for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
```

Answer (score 2):

A typical `for` loop would have 2 semi-colons as standard.

```
for(i=0; i<whatever; i++)
```

What you have there, in place of the `<` less than sign is a `&lt;`, which is an HTML encoding for the less than character. there is a problem however because there's a space between `t` and `;`, so it won't actual produce the less than symbol as desired.

`&lt ;` Should be `&lt;`

I am assuming that wherever this for loop is coming from is in some sort of HTML or XML file and they were trying to escape the less than character as to avoid the parser thinking it's the beginning of a tag. In which case, I'd probably look into `CDATA` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`&lt;` is the [character entity](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html) equals to <,

So actually your code is equivalent to:

```
for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
```

[Here is list of special entities.](http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/special.html)

Answer (score 1):

**for( ; ; )** it is equivalent to **while(true).**

A for-loop has three elements:

**initializer**

**condition (or termination expression)**

**increment expression**

**for(;;)** is not setting any of them, making it an endless loop.

Reference: [Description here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

**Semicolons** are required inside the **parenthesis** of the for loop.  The for loop is the only statement that **requires such semicolon placement**.

Comment: While accurate, I can't see how this is anything other than tangentially related to the question. OP _knows_ what a `for` loop is supposed to look like, they're questioning why this one _doesn't_ look like that.